# Proving that an intersection of two sets is in a ring of sets

Tags: measure-theory, ring-theory

There is a ring of sets given. Let's call in $R$. We know that $A, B \in R$. Now I am to prove that $A \cap B \in R$ too. I guess it must be quite easy but I really can't find the proper way to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$A\cap B=(A\cup B)\setminus((A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A))$

Comment: I can write that $A \cap B = (A^c \cup B^c)^c$ but we don't know whether $A^c, B^c \in R$

Comment: @Hendrra You're right... I was probably trying too hard. If you just draw a picture the new approach above should have seemed obvious to you.